# Post data is not being received into database but shows success result using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I implemented a new way to submit a form on my web page using javascript in order to achieve showing success results without reloading/refreshing the page. I am very new to Javascript and I am sure I am missing something obvious.

I know it's not due to database restrictions, I've double checked to make sure it wasn't some kind of foreign key error.

I know the php post query works as it still works with the original form I was using before implementing javascript.

New Code:

```
<div id="contact_form">
<form name="contact" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="likesid" id="likesid" size="30" value="4" class="text-input" />

    <input type="hidden" name="likerid" id="likerid" size="30" value="117" class="text-input" />

      <br />

    <button style="width: 100%; border: none; background:none!important; background-color: transparent; cursor: pointer;" type="submit" name="unlikestatus" class="button" id="submit_btn">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-fw ss-large ss-text-blue"></i>
    </button>   

  </fieldset>
</form>

</div>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
      // validate and process form here
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {
      // validate and process form here

      $('.error').hide();
      var likesid = $("input#likesid").val();
        if (likesid == "") {
        $("label#likesid_error").show();
        $("input#likesid").focus();
        return false;
      }
        var likerid = $("input#likerid").val();
        if (likerid == "") {
        $("label#likerid_error").show();
        $("input#likerid").focus();
        return false;
      }

  var dataString = 'likesid='+ likesid + '&likerid=' + likerid;
  //alert (dataString);return false;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "simpletest.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
      $('#message').html("<h2>Liked!</h2>")
      .hide()
      .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        $('#message').append("");
      });
    }
  });
  return false;   

    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm not sure how javascript works in this case, but in PHP, I am using this line

```
if(isset($_POST['likestatus']))
```

And I don't see anywhere in my javascript that refers to "likestatus", I'm assuming this might be the issue? Is it possible?

I got this javascript code and altered it from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59)

Comment: check dataString .likesid, likerid are sending to server.not likestatus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP post request is looking for a field on your form where name='likestatus', which doesn't exist in the code above. To pass that value into the ajax call, you need to first add that field to the HTML form.

You also need to add it to the javascript variable, dataString, that is being passed to the PHP call via ajax.

Explanation:

The **data** property on the ajax call defines all of the variables that are passed to the **url** property specified. If the ajax call goes through, it will trigger the **success** property, which doesn't necessarily mean the data was saved in the database.

Comment: You sir, are 100% correct, I did exactly as you said and It worked. Thank you!